# Custom Backend data for map to JSON file?

Tags: json, google-maps, wp-localize-script, map

I want to create a map in the frontend with data that is populated with Point of interests. I want to manage the POI data in the backend but need a generated JSON file from that backend data that talks with the JavaScript in the frontend.

If I wanted to implement it manually, how would I do that?

Comment: You would likely want to create a custom post type with custom fields to store your data, and look into AJAX or [wp_localize_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/) to get your data to the front end

Comment: Hi Christophe, welcome to WPSE. Plugin recommendations [are off-topic here](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1217/update-our-faq-and-abandon-theme-plugin-recommendations) so I've edited your question to remove that part of your request. As for the rest of your request, it is likely too broad for us to answer; are you able to edit your question with some rundown of what you have tried so far, so we can help specifically with where you're stuck?

Comment: Hi @TimMalone, thanks for your answer and your notices. The problem is, I came here for techninal opinions and instructions because I don't have any clue where to start or what to search for to solve my issue. I expected an answer like that from czerspalace which shows me a direction and which concepts of WordPress are available to deal with JSON file export. 
I just need some technical advice which concepts I have to look into to figure it out for myself.

Comment: @christophe Opinions are not geared to the SE model.  I would encourage you to read [ask] and [tour].  Based on your rep and if you are looking for an opinion and guidance you're free to visit the chatroom.  However, after your edit your question shows no effort, research or shows you attempted anything and it would require a very long tutorial to complete and that isn't in scope.

Comment: @Darth_Vader I don't want a tutorial here, I need someone to tell me what concept I am missing or I have to look into, so I can search for my problem properly. Right now I don't have a clue if it's even possible what I want to achieve nor which concepts of WP are a prerequisite. I didn't know that SE would be so dogmatic. I am looking for advice which direction I should head, not for someone to create a tutorial or code snippets for me.

Comment: When you state, "how would I do that", that can be taken as you're asking for a tutorial.

Comment: I just need a keyword so I can deep dive into the concept to learn it. Just a keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the JSON REST API -  http://v2.wp-api.org - It lives as a plugin now but will eventually be part of WP Core - https://wordpress.org/plugins/rest-api/

To manually output JSON, use a combination of wp-ajax to handle requests and `wp_json_encode()` / `wp_send_json_success` for simple PHP Objects and Arrays.  See https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: Thank you so much, that's everything I wanted. Now I have a starting point!